# How to make a QTextFrame with rounded corners?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, desktop-application, qt6

**Main Application**: I am trying to creating a text editor with Qt6, C++, and QTextEdit.

**Goal**: I want to implement functionality that will allow me to insert a code block in my rich text editor, much like that you usually see in StackOverflow. The code block should have round corners, its own background, foreground, borders, font.

**What I have done**: The closest solution I have found is using a QTextFrame.

**Code**:

```
QTextFrameFormat frameFormat;
frameFormat.setBackground(Qt::lightGray);
frameFormat.setBorder(1);
frameFormat.setBorderStyle(QTextFrameFormat::BorderStyle_Solid);



frameFormat.setMargin(0);
frameFormat.setPadding(4);
ui->textEditor->textCursor().insertFrame(frameFormat);
```

Obviously, this already works well, but I can not create rounded borders or play with the font.

Once again, the end goal is to insert in the QTextEdit a code block that is stylistically very similar to those in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a `QTextFrame` with rounded corners.

I have answered similar question. I utilized the answer again.

.h

```
#ifndef TEXTEDIT_H
#define TEXTEDIT_H

#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QTextFrame>

class TextEdit: public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:


    explicit TextEdit(QObject* parent=nullptr);


    void drawFrames(QPainter &p, QTextFrame* f);

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* e);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e);

};


#endif // TEXTEDIT_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "TextEdit.h"
#include <QAbstractTextDocumentLayout>
#include "qpainter.h"

TextEdit::TextEdit(QObject* parent)
{

}

void TextEdit::drawFrames(QPainter& p, QTextFrame* f)
{
    QTextFrameFormat format = f->frameFormat();
    if (format.property(1) == "code")
    {
        QRectF rf = document()->documentLayout()->frameBoundingRect(f);

        QPen pen = p.pen();
        QBrush brush = p.brush();
        brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
        pen.setWidth(1);

        brush.setColor(Qt::gray);
        p.setPen(pen);
        p.setBrush(brush);

        p.drawRoundedRect(rf, 10, 10);
    }


    QList<QTextFrame*> lf = f->childFrames();
    foreach (QTextFrame* cf , lf)
    {
        drawFrames(p, cf);
    }


}

void TextEdit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
{
    QTextDocument * doc = document();
    QTextFrame* rootFrame = doc->rootFrame();
    QPainter p = QPainter(viewport());
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    drawFrames(p, rootFrame);
    QTextEdit::paintEvent(e);

}

void TextEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* e)
{

    if (e->key() == Qt::Key_1)
    {
        QTextCursor tc = textCursor();
        QTextFrameFormat f;
        f.setMargin(5);

        f.setProperty(1, "code");

        tc.insertFrame(f);

        return;
    }
    
    QTextEdit::keyPressEvent(e);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "TextEdit.h"



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    TextEdit e;
    e.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

You can specify the type of frame by setting property.

[image]